# How can I sum values in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL.
I have a P_id that should be able to find the max value. I want to show the sum of two formulas by following:

```
    Then 

          Sum(max(pval)*S_val*Estimate)
          Sum(max(pval)*P_val*Analyze)
    Finally sum the Both above
```

I used the following function but it gives me an error:

```
               
>    id Display P_id    P_val   Analyze S_id    S_val   Estimate       
>    70 Data1   1       1       178     0       0       0      
>    71 Data2   1       0       0       1       3       50
```

```
SELECT  SUM( max(pval)*S_val*Estimate) + Sum( max(pval)* P_val * Analyze) from DATA where pid='1'
```

This results in:

- A: 1*178
- B: 1*3*50
- Sum(A+B): 328

Comment: Could you edit you SQL so it's actually readable? :)

Comment: Please post the actual result you want to get.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Where did you get that A = 178? I see S_val = 0 and Estimate = 0, so max(pval)*S_val*Estimate should be = 0 too? It's hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot nest aggregate functions - `SELECT SUM(MAX(x))` will always error.

You can get the inner value in a subquery instead:

```
SELECT
  SUM(maxpval * S_val * Estimate),
  SUM(maxpval * P_val * Analyze)
FROM
  yourTable
  JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(P_val) AS maxpval FROM yourTable
  ) AS dt;
```